# Extract filename from HTML text using regexp

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex

I have this HTML code (just an example):

```
Sem vestibulum blandit nostra, nullam imperdiet, pellentesque vel wisi sit fusce purus mi, porttitor lorem. Bibendum non phasellus ut ipsum massa sed, interdum per, facilisis facilis luctus fermentum et donec, tristique tristique non.</p>
<p align="justify"><a class="nemo" href="http://myserver.com/images/blogs/65/emo_by_bebz.jpg"><img style="max-width:256px; max-height:256px" src="http://myserver.com/images/blogs/65/emo_by_bebz_thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
<p align="justify">Ante sed pede adipiscing morbi, ut aliquam orci, nunc tempus lectus suspendisse, sem at sit ullamcorper augue.
```

and i want to replace all `<a class="nemo" ... </a>` width this: **{image src=emo_by_bebz_thumb.jpg}** using javascript and a regular expresion. As a starting point i have this regex:

```
<a class=\"nemo\"[^>]*>(.*?)src="(.*?)"[^>]*></a>
```

it works, but $2 gives me only the full image path and i only want the filename. Any ideas??

thanks in advance,

Comment: why did you tag this with php?

Comment: presumably because that's what he's using for whatever is stripping the strings and leaving himself open to solutions that utilize PHP functionality vs just a raw RegExp solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get it in $3 if you use this regex:

```
<a class=\"nemo\"[^>]*>(.*?)src="(.*)\/(.*?)"[^>]*></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there anything that speaks against using a real parser for this? Regex should be avoided for such a job.

Here is a nice write-up how to use `libxml` and `DOMDocument` for this: [Extracting data from HTML](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0081_parse_html_extract_data_from_html.html), written by Kore Nordmann.

The following code is his (there's not much missing to make it work for you):

```
<?php 
$oldSetting = libxml_use_internal_errors( true ); 
libxml_clear_errors(); 

$html = new DOMDocument(); 
$html->loadHtmlFile( 'http://kore-nordmann.de/blog.html' ); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html ); 

$links = $xpath->query( '//a' ); 
foreach ( $links as $link ) 
{ 
  echo $link->getAttribute( 'href' ), "\n"; 
} 

libxml_clear_errors(); 
libxml_use_internal_errors( $oldSetting ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple: add to your regex the following instruction, (in words / pseudo code),

```
Replace `<a class=\"nemo\"[^>]*>(.*?)src="(.*?)"[^>]*></a>`
Ignore the first 5 / and their content
```